# Hierarchical block diagram

Tags: diagrams, trees, structure

I've tried to use the `forest` package to make a 'hierarchical block diagram' like this.
[image: hierarchical block diagram]

It seemed that my effort can never meet my goal.
I also tried Visio, and it didn't work well.
So I came back to Latex and need advice from you guys.
Thank you so much.

Thanks a lot Mr. bibra.
I put your code into mine, and the result looked like this:
[image]

The branches are not orthogonal as yours.
Could you give me a hint or more information?
Still one more question, can this 'tree diagram' be saved as a figure
or which form should it appear in my work so I can reference it any where?

@ js bibra
I think I found what's wrong with my tex code.
In the preamble, before the line

```
\usepackage[edges]{forest}
```

I accidentally added the following line (which could happened any time before I post this question and was looking for a solution on line)

```
\usepackage[linguistics]{forest}
```

Everything is OK if I remove this line.
Thank you so much again @js bibra.

Comment: How close did you get with the forest package?  Could you post that attempt?  Even if it doesn't compile, it would give us a starting point.

Comment: @T.M.  please have alook at the answer below

Comment: you can adapt the package FAST http://enseignement.allais.eu/page-latex

Comment: @T.M. request to accept the answer if it meets the requirement by clicking the green tick mark on left side of the answer -- a green tick will appear once you accept the answer

Answer (score 7):

This should point you in the right direction  -- I have not filled up the exact text

Level 0 is the root level or origin and so on -- the code is self-explanatory

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[edges]{forest}

\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
        for tree={
            grow'=east,
            anchor=west,
            node options={draw, thick, font=\sffamily, align=center, },
            edge={semithick},
            forked edges,
            l sep=4mm,
            s sep=2mm,
            fork sep = 2mm,           % new, distance from parent to branching point
            where level=0{rotate=90, anchor=center, fill=blue!20}{}, % new
            where level=1{s sep=1mm,fill=blue!20}{}, % new
             where level=2{s sep=1mm,draw=none}{},
              where level=3{s sep=1mm,draw=none}{},
%            where level=2{}{rotate=90, anchor=center} % new
%where n children={11}{rotate=90, anchor=center}{},
%where n children={2}{rotate=90, anchor=center, fill=blue!20}{},
%where n children=6{rotate=90, anchor=center}{},
%where n children=8{rotate=90, anchor=center}{},
        },
        [Mother branch,
        [Text
        [Text]
        [Text]
        [Text]
        [Text]
        [Text]
        ]
        [Text
        [Text[Text][Text]]
        [Text ]
        [Text]
        ]
        [Text]
        [Text]
        [Text]
        [Text]
        ]
    \end{forest}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank a lot @js bibra. After removing  \usepackage[linguistics]{forest}  in my preamble, everything is OK.

Comment: @T.M.  request to accept the answer if it meets the requirement by clicking the green tick mark on left side of the answer